# Will a default-constructed (empty) shared_ptr automatically be initialized to nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I had read from some blog that a default-constructed (empty) `shared_ptr` is automatically initialized to `nullptr`. But could not find any such explicit statement in the statndards.

I wrote a small snippet (Linux Compiled) to confirm this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base;

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> p;
    Base* b;

    if (p == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "p IS NULL \n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "p NOT NULL \n";
    }

    if (b == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "b IS NULL \n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "b NOT NULL \n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> p IS NULL 
>
> b NOT NULL
> ```

From this I see that the smart pointers are implicitly assigned `nullptr` at the time of Declaration. Can somebody confirm this behavior? Is it safe to use a `shared_ptr` without manually assigning a `nullptr` to it?

Comment: This link says so, too: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) tells us that the default constructor is identical to just passing a `nullptr` to the constructor:

```
constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept;                        (1)
constexpr shared_ptr( std::nullptr_t ) noexcept;        (2)
```

> 1-2) Constructs a shared_ptr with no managed object, i.e. empty shared_ptr

Also from the [C++ standard draft for 2017](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf):

> **23.11.2.2.1 `shared_ptr` constructors**
>
> ...
>
> `constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept;`
>     2 *Effects:* Constructs an empty `shared_ptr` object.
>     3 *Postconditions:* `use_count() == 0 && get() == nullptr`.

Answer (score 7):

This is covered in [[util.smartptr.shared.const]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/util.smartptr.shared.const#3)

> *Ensures:* `use_­count() == 0 && get() == nullptr`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I've got those mad ninja skills ;)